# How to prevent removal of docker images in kubernetes workers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm running on k8s custer v1.9 application in docker container. Every time а docker is failed and restarted, the docker image is removed. Is there any setting that could prevent it?
imagePullPolicy is set to IfNotPresent

Comment: Hello. I'm having a difficulty to understand your question. Could you please edit it? Have you meant by any chance that every time a **`Pod`** is failing and it's restarted is it possible to not remove the previous iteration of this `Pod` (like for debugging purposes)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the [ImagePullPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-names) in your K8s manifests to `IfNotPreset` (or delete it, since this is the default).

Comment: It's defined as imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

Comment: Interesting - how do you know that the images have been removed?

Comment: This image has corrupted layer and can't be pooled from the local registry. I have it saved as .tar and can do "docker load -i image.tar" instead of pull. When the container is failed, it can't get back up because the image is gone.

Comment: If you have to load this image onto the local registry of your worker nodes manually, try ImagePullPolicy "Never", so that K8s does not try retrieving it from the remote registry.